# Maya Python - File node not updated during script runtime

Tags: maya

I'm writing a Python script that loads a file node and sets up some of its attributes. Then I question that node about its coverage. I want to get those values to later set up scene resolution:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
...

covX = mc.getAttr('fileNodeShape.coverageX')
covY = mc.getAttr('fileNodeShape.coverageY')

mc.setAttr('defaultResolution.width', covX)
mc.setAttr('defaultResolution.height', covY)
```

However, if I print covX and covY, I always get 1 and 1. It's just as if the file node wasn't fully loaded during script runtime, and that coverage had only its final values at the end (if I later check my file node in the attribute editor, both values are OK).

Is there something to do? I tried to check Preferences > Settings > Files/Projects > Image Files > Automatically reload updated image files, but this doesn't change anything...

Thanks!